# How to access static variable from Cypress test file

Tags: cypress

**Page File:**

```javascript
class DriveGridPage 

{ 
    static driveName = FileStoreCommonComponent.randomStringGenerator(5) 
} 
export default new DriveGridPage()
```

**Test File:**

```javascript
import DriveGridPage from "../../pom/app_modules/drive/drive_grid_page"

it("Create New Team Drive", () => {
const driveName = DriveGridPage.driveName
DriveGridPage.inputFileOrFolderName('Team Drive - ' + driveName)
})
```

While running the test, getting `driveName` `undefined`.

How to access static variable `driveName` from my page file?

Comment: Are you sure that `FileStoreCommonComponent.randomStringGenerator(5)` isn't returning `undefined`? If you hard code a string on driveName, do you see the same issue?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is you are exporting an instance of the class with `export default new DriveGridPage()`, but static members are accessed from the class definition.

See [MDN - static](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static)

> Static properties **cannot be directly accessed** on instances of the class

So, you can change things up to export the class rather than the instance

```js
class DriveGridPage { 
  static driveName = FileStoreCommonComponent.randomStringGenerator(5) 
} 
export DriveGridPage
```

```js
import DriveGridPage from "../../pom/app_modules/drive/drive_grid_page"

it("Create New Team Drive", () => {
  const driveName = DriveGridPage.driveName   // returns the static value
  const driveGridPage = new DriveGridPage()   // make instance here
  driveGridPage.inputFileOrFolderName('Team Drive - ' + driveName)
})
```